# Twitter API attitude operator doesn't work

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have been using Twitters search API (via the [node-twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-twitter) module) and I am running into an issue with the attitude operator. I am looking to get both positive and negative tweets about a certain subject. Currently though they return identical results. Here is my code that calls the API.

```
// Add since ID for future requests
twitterSearchClient.search(
    {'q'          :'xmas+%3A%28',
     'lang'       : 'en',
     'count'      : 100,
     'result_type': 'recent'},
    function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + (error.code ? error.code + ' ' + error.message : error.message));
        }

        if (result) {
            var requestDetails = result.search_metadata;
            var results = result.statuses;
            var resultsLength = results.length;
            var r;
            var data;
            var d;

            console.log(resultsLength);

            for (var i=0; i<resultsLength; i++) {

               console.log(r.text);
            }   
        }
    }
);
```

As you can see I am using the fully urlencoded value like the example in the documentation. I have also tried using xmas+%3A) for positive and xmas+%3A( for negative but this returns a 401 unauthorised error for some reason.

Has anyone ran into this issue or has a solution.

If you have any future questions I will be happy to answer them

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `xmas%20%3A%28` for negative tweets and `xmas%20%3A%29` for positive? (No `+` but `%20`) ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I just gave it a try and I am getting the same result :(

Comment: what `npm` package are you using?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/istrategylabs/node-twitter

Answer (score 1):

Per twitter's docs

> Please, make sure to [URL encode](https://twitter.com/search-home) these queries before making the request

When going to that url and typing in your search `xmas :)` I got this query

`https://twitter.com/search?q=xmas%20%3A)`

as you can see `xmas :)` = `xmas%20%3A)` and `xmas :(` ends up being

`https://twitter.com/search?q=xmas%20%3A(`

`xmas :(` = `xmas%20%3A(`

If you still do not get different results (you can compare the results to what get when doing the search on the link above) then it is not the query, but maybe how you are making the call. Will need additional information if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you but I have tried that already, but a plus sign is valid as it says in the documentation. "Note that the space character can be represented by “%20” or “+” sign." Also this was already suggested in the comments of the question.

Comment: I would recommend using encodeURIComponent, as this will encode the plus sign in a string.  Many server-side decodes will translate `+` to a space... encodeURIComponent will give the most predictable results.

Comment: Using encodeURIComponent resulted in a 401 error, which after some trail and error was cause by a parenthesis in the URI. That was the reason why I decided not to use it.

Comment: @gmaniac, your queries are incorrect. `https://twitter.com/search?q=xmas%20%3A)`, for example, does not search for positive sentiment tweets but rather searches for tweets literally containing the characters `:)`...

Comment: @Jim if it does not work then something else is incorrect. per their documentation https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators it looks like they still use it for positive and negative attitude.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, have you tried not encoding your query?  The client may well be encoding it on your behalf.

```
...
'q': 'xmas :(',
...
```

*NOTE: You do not mention, or link to which twitter client ([via npm?](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=twitter+search)) that you are using.*

---

I can't speak for your specific issues, when I search via the form on the site I do get different results, and the queries are URI encoded...  When you are passing input to a remote query string, I would recommend using `encodeURIComponent('xmas :)')` for your input values, this will yield the most predictable results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I have already tried this. The encodeURIComponent() function was the cause of the 401 error that I mentioned. After some trial and error I realised that it was due to a parenthesis in the URL, which is odd.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Yeh sorry for the delay been really busy